# DirectX 10 Screen Capture for Battlefield 3

Tags: windows, vb.net, directx, screenshot

I am having trouble getting a screen capture when i play Battlefield3. I know that i must capture usig DirectX, so i have made some search and found this :

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D
    Imports Microsoft.DirectX

    Public Class form1
       Public Shared Function CaptureScreenshot(ByVal Device As Direct3D.Device, ByVal Filename As String, ByVal ImageFormat As Direct3D.ImageFileFormat) As Boolean
    Dim B As Direct3D.Surface
    Try
        B = Device.GetBackBuffer(0, 0, DirectX.Direct3D.BackBufferType.Mono)
        Direct3D.SurfaceLoader.Save(Filename, ImageFormat, B)
        B.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
Public Shared Function CaptureScreenshot(ByVal Device As Direct3D.Device, ByVal Filename As String) As Boolean
    Return CaptureScreenshot(Device, Filename, Direct3D.ImageFileFormat.Bmp)
End Function
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CaptureScreenshot(Device, "capture.jpg", Direct3D.ImageFileFormat.Bmp)
End Sub

End Class
```

but it does not work. It says :
Error 2 'Device' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.
Error   1   'DirectX' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I know that the game uses DirectX 11 / DirectX 10.
I am a member of a clan in BF3 and we want the program to take screen shots at a time interval, the timers is not a problem, i can do that but i can't manage to resolve the 2 errors. Thanks in advance and i appreciate the time you are spending to view this thread. Sorry for my English.

Comment: So what's the question? Have you tried the code? If so and it doesn't work, what's wrong with it?

Comment: +1, I have the same problem and need solution